# Json data to Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a complex JSON data. I want to convert this JSON directly to pandas dataframe.

The required JSON has 23 records.
 I am pasting 2 records only.

```
       {"total":1,"page":1,"records":23,"rows": 
       [{"indexdailywaterlevel":0,
       "indexcount":1,
       "stationid":347,
       "stationcode":"P.17",
       "basinname":"ปิง",
        "amphurname":"บรรพตพิสัย",
       "provincename":"นครสวรรค์",
       "braelevel_qmax":"39.80|2990.00",
       "waterlevelvalueQ7":"35.14|248.00|8.2943143812709||",
      "waterlevelvalueQ6":"35.17|259.00|8.66220735785953||",
       "waterlevelvalueQ5":"35.27|293.00|9.79933110367893||",
       "waterlevelvalueQ4":"35.19|266.00|8.89632107023411||",
        "waterlevelvalueQ3":"35.14|248.00|8.2943143812709||",
       "waterlevelvalueQ2":"35.02|207.00|6.92307692307692||",
       "waterlevelvalueQ1":"35.05|217.00|7.25752508361204||",
       "weekaverage":"35.14|248.29|8.30387004300048||",
       "capacitypercent":7.25752508361204,
        "wlstatus":null}, 
        {"indexdailywaterlevel":0,
       "indexcount":2,
       "stationid":345,
       "stationcode":"N.67",
       "basinname":"น่าน",
       "amphurname":"ชุมแสง",
    "provincename":"นครสวรรค์",
    "braelevel_qmax":"28.30|1579.00",
    "waterlevelvalueQ7":"20.14|215.00|13.6162127929069||",
     "waterlevelvalueQ6":"20.10|210.00|13.299556681444||",
    "waterlevelvalueQ5":"20.00|202.00|12.7929069031032||",
    "waterlevelvalueQ4":"20.00|202.00|12.7929069031032||",
    "waterlevelvalueQ3":"19.98|200.00|12.6662444585181||",
    "waterlevelvalueQ2":"19.95|198.00|12.5395820139329||",
    "waterlevelvalueQ1":"19.95|198.00|12.5395820139329||",
    "weekaverage":"20.02|203.57|12.8924273952773||",
    "capacitypercent":12.539582013932868,
    "wlstatus":null}]}
```

The record starts from  "indexdailywaterlevel":0 and ends at "wlstatus":null .

I tried 
         pd.read_json(data.json)
It is giving output as

```
      page 1 ,records 23{'provincename': 'à¸™à¸„à¸£à¸ªà¸§à¸£à¸£à¸„à¹Œ', 
      'waterlevelvalueQ6': 
      '35.17|259.00|8.66220735785953||', 'wlstatus': None, 
     'waterlevelvalueQ1': '35.05|217.00|7.25752508361204||', 'indexcount': 
      1, 'waterlevelvalueQ4': '35.19|266.00|8.89632107023411||', 
      'basinname': 'à¸›à¸´à¸‡', 'waterlevelvalueQ3': 
       '35.14|248.00|8.2943143812709||', 'indexdailywaterlevel': 0, 
       'stationcode': 'P.17', 'waterlevelvalueQ5': 
        '35.27|293.00|9.79933110367893||', 'weekaverage': 
      '35.14|248.29|8.30387004300048||', 'waterlevelvalueQ7': 
      '35.14|248.00|8.2943143812709||', 'braelevel_qmax': '39.80|2990.00', 
   'capacitypercent': 7.25752508361204, 'amphurname': 'à¸šà¸£à¸£à¸žà¸•à¸žà¸ 
   ´à¸ªà¸±à¸¢', 'waterlevelvalueQ2': '35.02|207.00|6.92307692307692||', 
    'stationid': 347},total 1
```

All the columns are in a single 3rd column.How can i divide it different 
 columns?

Comment: All the json values are in a single column.I want to distribute it into different columns..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the data you want is in the rows column. You can use:

```
pandas.io.json.json_normalize(df["rows"])
```

This will produce:

```
amphurname basinname braelevel_qmax capacitypercent  ...
??????????  ???      39.80|2990.00   7.257525
??????      ????     28.30|1579.00   12.539582
...
```

Check out [pandas.io.json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html)

Comment: If this anderes your question pleased accept the answer.